# Phonegap 3.5.0 - plugins not working once uploadd to build

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, cordova-plugins

I've just got started with Phonegap and am using the latest version (3.5.0).

I set up an app using the [CLI](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.5.0/guide_cli_index.md.html) and am having trouble with plugins once uploaded to [build.phonegap.com](http://build.phonegap.com).

I followed all the steps on the CLI page above to create a simple app that which simply does a notification alert when the device is loaded.

example:

```
navigator.notification.alert(
        'Welcome to the app',  // message
         okay,                  // callback
        'Welcome',             // title
        'Continue'             // buttonName
);
```

This works fine in the emulator however when i upload the app to PG build (via zip file) and download it to a device there is no notification.

I notice when i upload my app to build the plugins tab says 'This application has no plugins.' which im guessing is the issue.

Im using the following to add plugins locally: cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs

Do i need to do something else to get them as part of the build?

Answer (score 9):

I suggest you read [the phonegap build docs](http://docs.build.phonegap.com/).

You have to put plugins into your config.xml using `<gap:plugin name="plugin.name" />` in order to use with build and you can use only certified plugins present in https://build.phonegap.com/plugins

So for your sample, you would add the following line to your config.xml :

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs" />
```

Using CLI, for example:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
```

does not add plugins to your config xml, you need to do this as mentioned above as well for  them to work with build.

Note: Starting with cordova 3.4 the config.xml file is no longer created in www folder so you must move it in there yourself. When uploading to build you only need to zip up the www folder which contains config.xml, index.html, js, css, img etc

Comment: Thanks quickfix, i actually had this in my config.xml, i figured out the issue was that the config xml was created outside of the www folder for some reason. I've posted my solution below http://stackoverflow.com/a/25207644/713797

Answer (score 1):

I used the following to create my app:

```
cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

for some reason this created the config.xml at top level and not in my www folder (where it should be) additionally its worth noting that when installing plugins via CLI like so:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.dialogs
```

You still need to add the plugin to config.xml ie:

```
<gap:plugin name="org.apache.cordova.dialogs"/>
```

Otherwise they wont apepar in the plugins tab in build.phonegap.com

Comment: starting with cordova 3.4 config.xml is no more created in www folder but at the root of the project. I no more use PG build but I think I remember successfully building uploading the whole project in the zip (not just www). And an other thing, at least with other versions of cordova and pg build a project created with cordova cli had a bad header in the config.xml wich refered a dtd not compatible with PG build plugins.

Comment: Thanks quickfix, yes the bad header is you need to add xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0" to the top. AM i correct in saying you need to move the config into the www folder yourself? Can you update your answer to include all this for anyone else who has similar issue and ill accept it, cheers

Comment: no time right now, but maybe can you do it if you have access to the edit button? or update your own and accept it.